# Zero magnetic field and zero electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

A charged particle, passing through a certain region of space, has a velocity whose magnitude and direction remain constant.

- If it is known that the external magnetic field is zero everywhere in this region, can you conclude that the external electric field is also zero?
- If it is known that the external electric field is zero everywhere, can you conclude that the external magnetic field is also zero?

Comment: Hi Abir and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Actually I understand it is sort of homework type and I also know the answer , But I asked it because I couldn't understand its answer . So please help me understand by explaining.

Comment: @AbirMahmud I can't really understand your comment, but if you don't understand my answer, ask for clarification in a comment below that.

Answer (score 4):

The Lorentz force acting on a charge $q$ moving with velocity ${\bf v}$ through a region of space with a uniform electric field ${\bf E}$ and uniform magnetic field ${\bf B}$ is ${\bf F} = q ({\bf E} + {\bf v}\times{\bf B})$. If the velocity of the charge is constant there is no force acting on it. If you know that ${\bf E} = 0$ then all you know is that ${\bf v}\times{\bf B} = 0$. It could be that ${\bf B}$ is non zero and ${\bf v}$ is in the same direction as the magnetic field. However, the case ${\bf B}=0$ means ${\bf E}$ must be zero.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The relation of the electric and magnetic fields are described by the [Maxwell Equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%20equations). The essence of them is that the time derivate of one of these fields is the curl ($\approx$ space derivate) of the other. So, they are relations between the derivates.

For example, if the fields are constant in time, they are unrelated. For example, around a static magnet there is no electric field.

More exactly: if one of the fields is static in time, the other can be any curl-free value, including the constant zero one.

Comment: But surely using the Lorentz force law, and that $v$ is constant, so $F=ma=0$, and one of $E$ or $B$ is zero...

Comment: @snulty Maybe any EM field can cause it, in which the electric and magnetic forces negate eachother.

Comment: The answer by Jim is what I was getting at